# regex for at least 2 empty space?

Tags: ruby, regex

i need to ignore anything that is one space, and empty space at least bigger than one space should be matched...

```
"MARY   HAD A LITTLE            LAMB"
```

i expect

```
"MARY", "HAD A LITTLE", "LAMB"
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Whitespace matching is `\s` and you can supply a minimum and maximum in curly braces. You can also omit either of them, like so:

```
\s{2,}
```

So your code would be like:

```
"MARY   HAD A LITTLE            LAMB".split(/\s{2,}/)
```

[You can test it online here!](http://rubular.com/regexes/13240)

Answer (score 1):

Use this: `str.split(/\s{2,}/)`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/  */ /g'
```

replaces one or more space..

so i guess regex is,

```
<space><space>*
```